# find using contain with condition

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

hello I have the following models

`Restaurant(id, name)` 
`RestaurantMenu(id, name, restaurant_id)` [each restaurant has many main menus]
`RestaurantMenuItem(id, name, restaurant_menu_id)` [Each Menu has many menu items]

I need to find those `RestaurantMenu` which has at least 1 `RestaurantMenuItem`. If It has not then it shouldn't have to get the `RestaurantMenu` also. Atm it is giving me empty array `RestaurantMenuItem` which I don't want. I don't want an empty object.

```
$this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');

return $this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('RestaurantMenu.RestaurantMenuItem'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Restaurant.id' => $restaurant_id,
    ),
    'recursive' => 0
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by applying an `INNER` join with `RestaurantMenuItem` on the `RestaurantMenu` containment. That would cause `RestaurantMenu` to be selected only if at least 1 associated `RestaurantMenuItem` row exists, which should satisfy both of your conditions.

Unfortunately there's no `joins` and `group` option for containments, so one has to workaround this by for example **querying the `RestaurantMenu` data manually**, which should be pretty easy in your case, as you're only selecting a single `Restaurant` (btw, you should probably use the `first` finder instead of the `all` one in that case):

```
$restaurant = $this->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Restaurant.id' => $restaurant_id,
    ),
    'recursive' => 0
));

if ($restaurant) {
    // RestaurantMenu needs to have the containable behavior attached
    // in order for this to work
    $restaurant['RestaurantMenu'] = $this->RestaurantMenu->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'RestaurantMenuItem'
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'restaurant_menu_item',
                'alias' => 'RestaurantMenuItem',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'RestaurantMenu.id = RestaurantMenuItem.restaurant_menu_id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'RestaurantMenu.restaurant_id' => $restaurant_id,
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'RestaurantMenu.id'
        )
    ));
}

return $restaurant;
```

or by **using the `finderQuery` option** to define a custom query that includes the join:

```
return $this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'RestaurantMenu' => array(
            'finderQuery' => '
                SELECT
                  RestaurantMenu.*
                FROM
                    restaurant_menus AS RestaurantMenu
                INNER JOIN
                  restaurant_menu_items AS RestaurantMenuItem ON
                    RestaurantMenuItem.restaurant_menu_id = RestaurantMenu.id
                WHERE
                  RestaurantMenu.restaurant_id IN ({$__cakeID__$})
                GROUP BY
                  RestaurantMenu.id
            ',
            'RestaurantMenuItem'
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Restaurant.id' => $restaurant_id,
    )
));
```

This could also be applied in the `RestaurantMenu` association configuration in the `Restaurant` model.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > Joining tables](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > hasMany](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)**